# Add single quote and space in paraghaph title

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically add title in paragraph.but single with space text not fully add in title.

```
  <!docType Html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="file">
    </div>
    <script>
    var arr= ["bo'i kisahn","kishan"];

    var string="";
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    string =string + "<p title="+arr[i]+">kishan"+i+" </p>";
    }
    document.getElementById('file').innerHTML=string;
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: if you want to escape \'

Comment: Developer console should have given you warning on JS error.

Comment: @Ghostman '\' in good suggesion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the attribute value with `""` as it contains special characters

```
var arr = ["bo'i kisahn", "kishan"];

var string = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string = string + "<p title=\"" + arr[i] + "\">kishan" + i + " </p>";
}
document.getElementById('file').innerHTML = string;
```

```js
var arr = ["bo'i kisahn", "kishan"];

var string = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  string = string + "<p title=\"" + arr[i] + "\">kishan" + i + " </p>";
}
document.getElementById('file').innerHTML = string;
```

```html
<div id="file"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q7L6py40/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&apos;` to display single quote. 
Please check http://jsfiddle.net/r2m6tkf7/